# Single Language with Multi-regional website - How properly HREFLANG should implement

Tags: multiple-domains, multilingual, internationalization

I have all the details about how the Hreflang work and being implemented for proper serving.

Just need to clarify on some sort of content duplication issue.

One of my client has german language website with .eu **GEOTLD** and for wider reach he has created multi-regional website versions using subdirectory method like - /de/ (Germany), /at/ (Austria), /ch/ (Switzerland) and couple more countries with german speaking.

Now, My take on this is that it's ok to have those versions but the content being served on this regions has to be **UNIQUE**. - What's your view?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Rajesh.

Comment: Do I understand correctly - the question is whether de, at and ch pages in practically German must all have different contents in order to avoid double content penalties?

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify.